# Neo4j lazy loading while adding new relation

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm building a music advice system with Spring using neo4j.

```
// User Model
@Relationship (type = "LIKE", direction = OUTGOING)
private List likedArtists = new ArrayList ();

public void likeArtist (Artist artist) {
likedArtists.add (artist);
}
```

When i tried to like an artist, first it brings all the liked artists. Then adds it to the database. If the user likes 10.000 artists, these artists will be load to ram for every request.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?